# Lua Invalid HTTP request - Stripe API

Tags: ssl, https, lua, coronasdk, stripe-payments

I'm trying to write a module to communicate with Stripe's payment API. Already, i've come across trouble. I keep getting a response: ""Your client sent an invalid HTTP request." I've tried every possible thing I could think of..even b64..however, nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
description = "test"
email = "test@email.com"
api_key = "pk_test_4PRPYs3eM4HQx0ZMBOubGjoy"-- Don't worry, this is a public test key    ;)
cardNumber = "4242 4242 4242 4242"
fullName = "Test Name"
expMonth = "07"
expYear = "2016"
cvc = "432"


------------------------------------------------------------


 firstCard = {["number"] = cardNumber, ["exp_month"] = expMonth, ["exp_year"] = expYear, ["cvc"] = cvc, ["name"] = fullName}


StripeNewRegister = function () 
local json = require "json"
print ("test")
newCustomer = {["email"] = email, ["description"] = description} --["card"] = firstCard}


print(newCustomer)

local function networkListener( event )
    if ( event.isError ) then
        print( "Network error!" )
    else
        print( "RESPONSE: "..event.response )
        local data1 = event.response
        local resp1 = json.decode(data1)
        print(resp1)
        local error = resp1.error
        if error ~= nil then
            for i = 1, #resp1.error do
                print(resp1.error[i].type)
                print(resp1.error[i].message)
            end 
        end
        if error == nil then
                -- Print Functions 
        end  
    end
end

local key = {["Bearer"] = api_key}

local headers = { 
    ["Authorization Bearer"] = api_key
}

local params = {}
params.headers = headers
params.body = json.encode( newCustomer )

print( "params.body: "..params.body )

network.request( "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers", "POST", networkListener, params)



end

StripeNewRegister()
```

Comment: Can you write the error you are getting? I think the issue is related to encoding the e-mail and some variables for URL.